# Does Silverlight use a separate application domain for each browser tab?

Tags: silverlight, appdomain, applicationdomain

If the same Silverlight application is running in two web browser tabs, does each tab use a separate application domain?

If you know where Microsoft explicitly provides this information, please include a reference.

Answer (score 2):

Not direct from Microsoft, but one AppDomain per Silverlight instance:

- http://community.irritatedvowel.com/blogs/pete_browns_blog/archive/2007/11/07/How-Silverlight-is-Loaded-and-Instantiated.aspx
- http://wilcob.com/Wilco/Silverlight/asp-net-silverlight-component-development.aspx
- [blogs.msdn.com/apardoe/attachment/6644139.ashx](http://blogs.msdn.com/apardoe/attachment/6644139.ashx) (Powerpoint - Slide 15)

Answer (score 2):

To clarify Corbin's answer:

Its one AppDomain per instance of the Silverlight control, so that two Silverlight apps on the same page are segmented into AppDomains. Depending on the browser, there may be separations between tabs (e.g. IE8 and Chrome uses separate processes, whereas Firefox and IE7 do not). The only way to get two Silverlight instances to talk with each other is on the same page and to communicate through the HTML Bridge.

Answer (score 0):

The browser is completely in control of the tabs, and should keep them separate for obvious security reasons.